# How to make a POST REST call asynchronously in Java

Tags: java

I have tried a bunch of libraries to make a `REST POST` call using `HttpConnection` in Java asynchronously. I have tried many open source libraries and none of them seems to serve my purpose. Is there any way to do this in core Java.

Comment: Just use Jersey framework:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html

Comment: you can also use netty or apache http components async client

Comment: What are your expectations and why did the libraries you've tried not fulfil you expectations? What are your requirements?

Comment: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: @NimChimpsky How is this async?

Comment: @Zzz I assume there is an async option

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your requirements or expectations:

Here is a simple example without proper error handling which shows how an async HTTP call can be done using Java 8

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    Future<Object> futureResult = getObjectAsync();

    Object value = futureResult.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public static Future<Object> getObjectAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doHttpCall());
}

static Object doHttpCall() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = 
            (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://example.net/something").openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream())) {
            out.write("params as json");
        }

        try (InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream())) {
            // convert to Object
            return new Object();
        }

    } catch (IOException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```